# use webpack JS package in twig file

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, twig

I'm really beginner in `twig` and `webpack`.

I install some packages with `yarn` and use them inside `app.js`, but for some reasons I need some method of that packages inside of my `twig` files.
when I try to call a function, get error.

for example I install `boostrap-select` package and require that in `app.js`

```
// app.js

var $ = require('jquery');

require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap');
require('bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select');

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({});
})(jQuery);
```

everything is fine and work perfect but when call this package function inside of `twig` file like this

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('b/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({});
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I get error.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function

after search in google for one day I found out can not do that ... and I must do some extra things ... every examples are around of `jQuery`.

what about other packages? how define a function from `yarn` packages globally and use that in twig file.

I try all of this solutions but not work for me

```
funtionName = require('package path')
window.functionName =  functionName;
global.funtionNmae = functionName;
```

anyone has any solutions, I just need call a function in twig :(.

Answer (score 2):

"This error happens when your code (or some library that you are using) expects $ or jQuery to be a global variable. But, when you use Webpack and require('jquery'), no global variables are set."

[Symfony Frontend - FAQ and Common Issues](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html)

[jQuery and Legacy Applications](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/legacy-apps.html)

```
// app.js
var $ = require('jquery');
// ...
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is not about `$` or `jQuery`, `jQuery` is work fine and I set `$` globally, my problem is about any other npm package, like `bootstrap-select` or my own `javascript` `npm` package, how you use function of another packages in your project?